# Can you change Welcome Page Web Part Settings?

Tags: web-part, document-set, welcome-page

Lets say you have a Document Set, with a Web Part on it's Welcome Page. Let's say it has some custom settings (like a list name that it interacts with). Can you edit those settings like you would a web part placed on a normal page? Would/could you do this from any particular item's welcome page? Or is there some special way to access the generic "welcome page" for the content type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pages are aspx files and can be accessed either using the Browser or Using SharePoint Designer.

If using browser you can use Site Actions -> Edit Page. And then either add/edit the web parts that are available on the pages.